# Como buscar todas las palabras que contengan acento en SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando encontrar todos los registros que tienen acento en una tabla de usuarios. La idea es cambiar todas las palabras con Acento a su versión sin acento.

estoy probando con `LIKE`, de esta forma:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `usuarios`
WHERE `nombre` LIKE 'Á';
```

Pero eso no me está dando ningún resultado.
Igual intenté con `COLLATE utf8_bin`, de esta forma:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `usuarios` 
WHERE `nombre` 
like 'GARCÍA' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Pero esto me da error desde el principio diciendo que la palabra clave no está reconocida.
La verdad no tengo otra idea de como puedo hacerlo, alguien tiene una idea?

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacer eso? Considerando que si haces `like '%garcia%'` te devolverá sin problema registros con `'GARCÍA'`.

Comment: por que los registros que tienen acento son los que me generan conflicto. necesito reemplazar todos los registros que tengan acento

Comment: Tal vez el "conflicto" tiene una mejor solución que obligar a los usuarios a olvidarse de los acentos; intenta exponerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas **LIKE** necesitas agregarle **%**

Si lo agregas al final te buscará todas las palabras que empiecen con Á

```
LIKE 'Á%'
```

Si lo agregas al inicio te buscará todas las palabras que terminen con Á

```
LIKE '%Á'
```

Y si lo agregas al principio y al final te buscará todas las palabras que contengan Á

```
LIKE '%Á%'
```

Está última sería la que necesitas

Comment: no sabía que debia agregar el  %. Ya probé el query y me funciona, pero también me trae los registros que tienen una "A", sin acento. cómo puedo hacer que sean unicamente los que lleven "Á"?

Comment: Después de **LIKE** agregale `COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS` así como en [este ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/799b1/1/0)

Comment: Con tu código quedaría `SELECT * 
FROM usuarios
WHERE nombre COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS LIKE '%Á%';`